# How to get column from another table and insert into other table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two table `Cal_date` and `RPT_Invoice_Shipped`.

Table `cal_data` has columns

```
month_no
start_date
end_date
```

The table `RPT_Invoice_Shipped` has columns

```
Day_No
Date
Div_code
Total_Invoiced
Shipped_Value
Line_Shipped
Unit_Shipped
Transaction_Date
```

I am using below insert statement to insert data in `RPT_Invoice_Shipped` table.

```
insert into [Global_Report_Staging].[dbo].[RPT_Invoice_Shipped]
(Day_No, Date, Div_code, Total_Invoiced, Transaction_Date)
select , CONVERT(DATE,Getdate()) as Date, LTRIM(RTRIM(div_Code)), 
sum(tot_Net_Amt) as Total_Invoiced, (dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate())))
from [Global_Report_Staging].[dbo].[STG_Shipped_Invoiced]
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,Created_date )=CONVERT(DATE,Getdate()) 
group by div_code
```

while inserting in column `Day_No` in `RPT_Invoice_Shipped` table,
I have to use formula `Transaction_Date-start_date+1` where `Transaction_Date` is from `STG_Shipped_Invoiced` and `start_date` is from `Cal_date` table.

I was using `datepart (mm, Transaction_Date)` so it gives `month_no`, and this `month_no` we can join with `month_no` of `Cal_date` table and fetch `start_date` from `Cal_date` table, so that we can use `start_date` for formula `Transaction_Date-start_date+1`.

But I am getting difficulty to arrange this in above query.

Can you please guide me how to achive this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there a single row in `cal_data` for a given month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, I think this is what you are looking for

You need to do a `JOIN` with `cal_data` table `ON DATEPART(mm, STG.Transaction_Date) = C.month_no` and in your `SELECT` use `DATEDIFF(D,CONVERT(DATE,STG.Transaction_Date),C.start_date) + 1`

```
INSERT INTO [Global_Report_Staging].[dbo].[RPT_Invoice_Shipped]
(
    Day_No,
    Date,
    Div_code,
    Total_Invoiced,
    Transaction_Date
)

SELECT DATEDIFF(D,CONVERT(DATE,STG.Transaction_Date),C.start_date) + 1,
CONVERT(DATE,Getdate()) as Date,
LTRIM(RTRIM(div_Code)), 
SUM(tot_Net_Amt) as Total_Invoiced,
(DATEADD(DAY, -1, CONVERT(DATE, getdate())))
FROM [Global_Report_Staging].[dbo].[STG_Shipped_Invoiced] STG
INNER JOIN cal_data C
ON DATEPART(mm, STG.Transaction_Date) = C.month_no
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,Created_date ) = CONVERT(DATE,Getdate()) 
GROUP BY div_code,CONVERT(DATE,STG.Transaction_Date),C.start_date
```

Comment: Thanks Ughai, It works exact wat i wanted. Thank you very much for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

The `join` based on what you have specified

```
FROM [Global_Report_Staging].[dbo].[STG_Shipped_Invoiced] AS a
INNER JOIN Cal_date AS b  ON datepart (mm, Transaction_Date)) = a.month_no
```

---

```
insert into [Global_Report_Staging].[dbo].[RPT_Invoice_Shipped](Day_No, Date, Div_code, Total_Invoiced, Transaction_Date)
select Transaction_Date-start_date+1, CONVERT(DATE,Getdate()) as Date, LTRIM(RTRIM(div_Code)), 
sum(tot_Net_Amt) as Total_Invoiced, (dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate())))
from [Global_Report_Staging].[dbo].[STG_Shipped_Invoiced] AS a
INNER JOIN Cal_date AS b  ON datepart (mm, Transaction_Date)) = a.month_no
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,Created_date )=CONVERT(DATE,Getdate()) 
group by div_code
```

Comment: Thanks sqluser for your valuable time.
 i have already used ughai's query and it worked for me. Thanks you.....

Comment: No worries. The important thing is you found the proper answer and this post can be helpful for someone else in the future.